# Selecting vlaues from a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Given a dataframe of the format

```
A B C D 

.......

........
```

I would like to select the rows whose value in column B is greater than 0.6*the last value in column.For eg,

Input:

```
A B C

1 0 5

2 3 4

3 6 6

4 8 1

5 9 3
```

Output:

```
A B C

3 6 6

4 8 1

5 9 3
```

I am currently doing the following,

```
x = df.loc[df.tail(1).index,'B']
```

Which return a series object corresponding to the index and value of coulmn B of the last row of the dataframe and then,

```
new_df = df.[df.B > x]
```

But I am getting the error,

> ValueError: Series lengths must match to compare

How should I perform the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to 1st take the last value of column B using `tail` and multiply with `0.6`.

```
 df[df['B'] > df['B'].tail(1).values[0] * 0.6]
```